# Multiple people must be downloading files at the same time unless there is an update

Tags: java, spring-boot, file, optimization, blockchain

I have a blockchain system and I have a problem. The fact is that all participants mine the block on their computers and transfer it to the central servers, they also download the blockchain from there in order to continue mining from the current block. I am forced to synchronize the method, because if the file is updated and someone asks for a new version, then it may no longer be up to date. How can I make it so that until they change the file, several people can download at the same time, but as soon as the update begins, the rest continue to wait until the file is completely updated.
Ready to transfer coins if you are ready to participate
full code in github     https://github.com/CorporateFounder/unitedStates_final                  https://github.com/CorporateFounder/unitedStates_storage     my discord https://discord.gg/J5KF5NPJ

I expect this way of storing, when one member updates the code, then other members should not download, if the code is updated, then all members should have access to download.

Comment: I hope you have registered your security with the SEC and report every transaction on your blockchain to the IRS; otherwise, you're going to have a bit of an issue with the US government. I doubt that answers your question, which seems to be a rambling screed about synchronization. Try copy-on-write.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Elliot frisch I don't live in the US and am not a US citizen, why should I register there? Bro))

Comment: Elliot Frisch I am ready to send you two thousand coins if you go to my discord and we can discuss with you what you mean.